# How can i join another table with the primary of the other

Tags: mysql

I am creating an application like trello for that i am using MySQL as an database till now i have created authentication system using MySQL and express,node js now i want to create table for cards to save the data so, i want to know how can i link the users data to the users name.

I have created a table users with the following field id(primary key, auto_increment),name,email,password 
now i want to create a table card in which the users card would be present so how can i link user table column correspond to the particular
use, thanks in advance really new to backed

Comment: Put a foreign key to `users.id` in the `cards` table.

Comment: ok thanks @Barmar, can you tell me one thing how should i design the database for the trello cards as they are dynamic and can be created any no of times, so i should always create a new table or add column to the same table

Comment: One table for all cards

Comment: If they have dynamic number of fields, use an attribute-value table with a row for each field.

Comment: And design so that the cards table(s) does not need to have columns added when new cards come.

Comment: Right, that's what an attribute-value table is. It has one column `field_name`, another column `field_value`.

Comment: Ok thanks both of you, can you guts tell me where i will find the documentation or example related to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this lines of code can help you out a little. To get a better grasp of the topic.

```
-- This statement creates the cards table you may want to use (alternatively see Barmars Comment, this maybe a more professional solution)

CREATE TABLE Cards (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
customer_id INT,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50)
)

-- This statement then "connects" the tables. It makes the customer_id in the cards table a foreign key of the primary key of the customers table.
FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id)
```

After implementing this you can use JOIN in your queries to query multiple tables.

If you want more info, this video can help you understand the topic:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USaXlErI-QE